Is it possible to use .env in a React Web project?
I'm developing a PWA SPA with React Web, and practically everything is in .js.
I need to create environment variables in the Azure Portal, and as shown below I have already created some:
enter image description here
However, I can't use it in my project that is already hosted on the Azure Portal:
enter image description here
Any tip is welcome. I am sorry for my english.

You can embed these values at build time or use a backend language like PHP, Python or JavaScript to generate dynamic frontend JavaScript containing these values. You can't read these values with frontend JavaScript.

This question is similar to: What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem was resolved, I needed to make a request to the Azure Portal specialist team to restart the service after setting the environment variables.
